# Generate source files from XML

Tags: java, xml, maven, schema

I have the XML file which starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface name="AccountAPING" owner="BDP" version="1.0.0" date="now()" namespace="com.betfair.account.api"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <description>Account API-NG</description>
...
```

afterward there are various blocks, such as:

```
<operation name="getDeveloperAppKeys" since="1.0.0">
<description>
    Get all application keys owned by the given developer/vendor
</description>
<parameters>
    <request/>
    <simpleResponse type="list(DeveloperApp)">
        <description>
            A list of application keys owned by the given developer/vendor
        </description>
    </simpleResponse>
    <exceptions>
        <exception type="AccountAPINGException">
            <description>Generic exception that is thrown if this operation fails for any reason.</description>
        </exception>
    </exceptions>
</parameters>
</operation>

........

<simpleType name="Status" type="string">
    <validValues>
        <value name="SUCCESS">
            <description>Sucess status</description>
        </value>
    </validValues>
</simpleType>

........

<dataType name="TimeRange">
    <description>TimeRange</description>
    <parameter name="from" type="dateTime" mandatory="false">
        <description>from, format: ISO 8601)</description>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="to" type="dateTime" mandatory="false">
        <description>to, format: ISO 8601</description>
    </parameter>
</dataType>
```

How can I generate Java code from this using maven? I tried using "maven-jaxb2-plugin", but it can't parse this structure.

**Please note**

1. This is an XML file not not an xsd
2. I'm using Netbeans

Comment: are you using eclipse? maven downloaded `JaxB` packages? if you right click in the `XSD` file in Eclipse you can autogenerate java classes?

Comment: Java code can't be generated from XML. XSD is required to generate java models. http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html to generate XSD from XML and https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbah.html to generate java classes from XSD.

Answer (score 1):

To generate Java code from a schema file use XJC, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31848909/529256). Open a command prompt to the folder where you put your xsd file, and then generate java code you'll just need to type:

```
$ xjc nameOfSchemaFile.xsd
```

xjc is included with Java SDK.

Comment: I try xjc, but it cann't parse - many errors, such `[ERROR] s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'interface' is not a valid element in a schema document.
  line 3 of file:/D:/Projects/mavenproject1/src/main/xsd/SportsAPING.xml

[ERROR] schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'file:/D:/Projects/mavenproject1/src/main/xsd/SportsAPING.xml', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
  line 3 of file:/D:/Projects/mavenproject1/src/main/xsd/SportsAPING.xml`

Comment: Ah, you said you had a schema file, which ends with ".XSD". You can't do it with an ".XML" file. You'll have to write a schema file first. Take a look at the [XML Schema](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/default.asp) tutorial at the W3 School

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need the schema (xsd) that describes your xml sample. Without that schema you can not use Jaxb. You don't have a schema for the sample you shown `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` is not the schema for your xml.

You can use free on-line tools to generate schemas from xml, but you can't rely on this tools without review the automated schema.